# Spring Security loginPage Vs loginProcessingURL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

what is the difference between loginPage vs loginProcessingURL.
   `.formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("phone-number").passwordParameter("password")`

Seems to be loginProcessingURL is like post method once user submits the data in the login page but when I remove also it is working fine. What is the significance of loginProcessingURL and how does it differ from loginPage?

Answer (score 14):

The line `loginPage("/login")` instructs Spring Security

- when authentication is required, redirect the browser to /login
- we are in charge of rendering the login page when /login is requested
- when authentication attempt fails, redirect the browser to
  /login?error (since we have not specified otherwise)
- we are in charge of rendering a failure page when /login?error is
  requested
- when we successfully logout, redirect the browser to /login?logout
  (since we have not specified otherwise)
- we are in charge of rendering a logout confirmation page when
  /login?logout is requested

AND

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/login/process")
```

tells Spring Security to process the submitted credentials when sent the specified path and, by default, redirect user back to the page user came from. *It will not pass the request to Spring MVC and your controller.*

Refer [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html)

Comment: So In security context if I am not authenticated user and if I am trying to access the authenticated url then it should display the .loginPage("/login") right but why it is trying to go to the loginProcessingUrl("/login/process"). I am creating an empty security context SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext() in my filter. I have added the  filter in my SecurityConfig http.addFilter(new SecurityContextPersistenceFilter(securityRepository)); but whenever I am trying to access the authenticated url directly in browser it is redirecting me to loginProcessingUrl??

Comment: "It will not pass the request to Spring MVC and your controller."
This is NOT true. Tested by myself

Answer (score 1):

#### Purpose of `loginPage()`

The [`loginPage()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#loginPage(java.lang.String)) tells the framework where the user will be redirected when login is required. For example when you are not authorized to the page, you get redirected to this page. This page performs the login activity, for example when you implement a `loginForm()` or `oauth2Login()` like in my code using Google OAuth2,this page redirects to google login.

```
http.anonymous().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/images**").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                request.authenticate(response);
            })
            .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/google")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
```

#### Purpose of `loginProcessingUrl()`

The [`loginProcessingUrl()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#loginProcessingUrl(java.lang.String)) is the method that automatically set the rule `antMatchers("/thisUrl").permitAll()` to this URL so that when the response is returned (code, state, token, etc.) will be allowed to be GETed and this response is processed as you can see in the authenticate method of the request. Something more important is that this `loginProcessingUrl(`) tells that the **response should be processed to this URL**. Without this the `request.authenticate(response)` will not be executed and authentication will not be returned or otherwise you implement another algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Lets' say for example that you intend to use or configure your own login page then `.loginPage()` will help redirect to that page.

Moving forward, any data that is entered into your custom form will need processing or will need to be compared to that which is in the database or to that which is in the authentication Manager. Here, `.loginProcessingUrl` will help achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

May the following code segment from spring security source code will help you：

```
loginPage the login page to redirect to if authentication is required
```

```
loginProcessingUrl the URL to validate username and password
```

```
 DEFAULT_LOGIN_PAGE_URL = "/login"
```

```
/**
     * Updates the default values for authentication.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected final void updateAuthenticationDefaults() {
        if (loginProcessingUrl == null) {
            loginProcessingUrl(loginPage);
        }
             //...
        }
```