# Cyclicity in my program when I try to authorize (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, security

How do you do! I started learning Spring Security. I read some articles and I managed to do Spring MVC application. I need to implement custom form login and I did it but when I try to authorize I can't see needed view.

This is the security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin((form) ->
                        form.loginPage("/auth/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                                .failureUrl("/auth/login?error")
                                .permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

This is my view where I can authorize:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="f" method="post" action="/process_login">
  <label for="username">Введите имя пользователя</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
  <br/>
  <label for="password">Введите имя пользователя</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="login">

  <div th:if="${param.error}" style="color:royalblue">
      Неверный имя пользователя или логин
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller which return authorized form:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

This is my controller which return greeting:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getGreetings() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When I start my application I get my custom form. I type data from DB and I expect to see view "greeting" but I still see my custom form without any errors. This is cyclicity. I can type another combinations login and password but I won't see any errors.
P.S.: when I tried to authorize I get login and password for the user from my DB. I tried to enter the wrong username and password but I didn't see any information about errors.
I'm so sorry about my English skills but I can't to describe my problem better.

Comment: Please include code, not images of code: see [Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Edit the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll be more careful!

Comment: as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140629/spring-security-loginpage-vs-loginprocessingurl) `loginProcessingUrl()` *tells Spring Security to process the submitted credentials when sent the specified path and, by default, redirect user back to the page user came from. It will not pass the request to Spring MVC and your controller.* Most likely, if you just remove that line, it will work fine

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed my ConfigSecurity class. I removed "loginProcessingUrl()" but the problem described above persists. What do you think about view? Action = "/process_login". Maybe this's the problem too? If you think so what can I do that the problem left?