# Returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I tried to define my `SecurityFilterChain` in Java just like this, the `GET` request to `/game/**` was ok but when I tried to request to `/user/all` it returned 403 forbidden. Why it didn't return a 401 unauthorized instead of 403?

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                    .requestMatchers("/game/**",  "/gametype/**", "/publisher/**", "/platform/**" ).permitAll()
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                    .requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
            )
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .sessionManagement(a -> a
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            //                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            .build();
}
```

I tried to pass the Basic Auth username & password but it just returned a 403 Forbidden so I couldn't do more. First time learning Java.

Edited : I'm a little bit confused about the login flow. I didn't set anything about authority but it still return a 403, which means I don't have the authority to access that, at the beginning I thought I would return a 401 but not.

Comment: Newest update : I tried to add .formLogin() to have a login page on browser, after logged in it was OK but when I tried to pass the username and password in postman it returns the html for that login page, not what i need

Comment: You need to have multiple security configurations for that. Refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but you can try the code like below

```java
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        //authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
                        authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                );

        return http.build();
    }
```

Reference: [Login and Registration REST API using Spring Boot, Spring Security, Hibernate and MySQL Database](https://www.javaguides.net/2021/10/login-and-registration-rest-api-using-spring-boot-spring-security-hibernate-mysql-database.html)

Also I think you have to use `and()` to combine the matchers.
Refer: [java - How do I add HTTP basic auth for a specific endpoint with spring security? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524211/how-do-i-add-http-basic-auth-for-a-specific-endpoint-with-spring-security/76082092#76082092)

If you are doing login via UI, try to use `loginProcessingUrl`. Refer answers in [Spring Security loginPage Vs loginProcessingURL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140629/spring-security-loginpage-vs-loginprocessingurl)

Comment: I am a little bit confused, in the first line is  request matcher with "/api/**", the second line is "/api/auth/**". I'm new to this, so what is the difference between these urls?

Comment: I'm using a higher version of Spring and Spring Security so and() is deprecated :(

Comment: I think the first line is for allowing only HTTP GET methods whereas the second matcher allows anyone todo GET as well as POSTing of username/password submission via HTTP form submission (in case of UI) or via REST service.

Comment: Damn, first they changed antMatchers to requestMatchers. Now stuff like and() is changed. I am not up to date with spring framework so I would suggest you try to find a sample working project and proceed from there (https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web). Also try to enable and get the logs and see if you find any clue.

Comment: Yes, most of the documents I found at first was about the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, so it was a hard time trying to understand and convert these old things to the newest, maybe I have to do more research :(